# Why a struct pointer can't be declared by another struct pointer

Tags: c++, oop

Today, I have learned about the Binary Search Tree, and I am trying to implement it, but I got a problem.

Assume that I have a `Struct` like this:

```cpp
struct Node {
    int v;
    Node* left = NULL;
    Node* right = NULL;
}
```

Below it, I have:

```cpp
// At the beginning, root is NULL
Node* root = NULL;

Node* new_node(int v) {
     Node* n = new Node;
     n->v = v;
     return n;
}

void insert(int v) {
    // At the beginning, root is NULL

    Node* c = root;
    while (c != NULL) {
         if (v < c->v) {
              c = c->left;
         } else {
              c = c->right;
         }
    }

    c = new_node(v);
}
```

And in the main code, I tested my implementation by using this code:

```cpp
int main() {
    insert(5);
}
```

When I use `insert(5)`, in `insert` function, the variable `c` will be `root`, and because `root` at that time is `NULL`, so `c` will equal to `new_node(v)`. But when I print `root->v` it returns nothing.

Did I make something wrong??

Comment: `root` should be declared? There is no declaration of `root` in the code you posted

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the compiler error message

Comment: when I use insert(5), in ```insert``` function, varible c will be root, and because root at that time is null, so c will equal new_node(v). But when I print root->v it return nothing

Comment: "and because root at that time is null," why ? You wrote that in a comment, but a comment does not declare a variable and initialize it, you have to do that

Comment: Oh no, I forgot it, sorry guys

Comment: `c = new_node(v);` will modify the local variable `c`, but not `root`, after that line `root` is still `NULL`

Comment: suppose you have `int root = 0; int c = root; c = 42;`, thats not modifiying `root` and more or less the same is what your code does.

Comment: Can you explain me, why ```c```'s address wasn't pointed to ```root```'s address?

Comment: @largest That is not a prime, it is even.

Comment: I try to replace it by ```Node &c = root```, but nothing happens

Comment: Oh, i return 5, but when I add this ```insert(15)``` after ```insert(5)```, and I ```cout << root->right->v``` it return error ( maybe root->right is NULL )

Comment: you never modify `root`, it is always `NULL`

Comment: sorry, but can i know why it don't work like this: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_pointers.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you do not modify `root` after initialization. `root` is always `NULL`. This

```
Node* c = root;
// ...
c = new_node(v);
```

will not change `root`. It merely declares a local variable `c`, initializes it with the value of `root` and assigns a new value to it.

If you want to change the value of something inside a function you can pass it by reference, pointers are no different with respect to that. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int v;
    Node* left = NULL;
    Node* right = NULL;
};

Node* root = NULL;

Node*& find_insertion(Node*& ptr, int v){
    if (ptr == NULL) return ptr;
    if (v < ptr->v) {
        return find_insertion(ptr->left,v);
    } else {
        return find_insertion(ptr->right,v);
    }
}

void insert_at(Node*& ptr,int v){
    Node*& insertion = find_insertion(root,v);
    insertion = new Node;
    insertion->v = v;
}

void insert(int v){
    insert_at(root,v);
}

int main() {
    insert(5);
    std::cout << root->v;
}
```

Next you should take a look at smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) to avoid leaks or compilcated manual memory managment.

Comment: @TrầnGiaBảo note that the code was broken, i think i fixed it now